# Repopulate form_upload after validation in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have problem with repopulating form_upload after validation. Other input fields or selectboxes are repopulated with values, but it's not the case of upload input field. Is it possible somehow or not? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot repopulate a file type input. It's an HTML security limitation.